# Unexpected child metadata for parent type [CustomObjectTranslation]

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli, customobjecttranslation

I am receiving the below errro while validating the components in staging

> Validate deployment on sandbox ERROR running force:source:deploy:
> Unexpected child metadata
> [/home/circleci/ci_app/force-app/main/default/objectTranslations/Account-en_US/type_account.fieldTranslation-meta.xml]
> found for parent type [CustomObjectTranslation]

In case anyone has faced a similar issue, could you please share how could this be resolved

Comment: At a glance, it looks like you're including a translation for an Account field (type_account) without including the type_account custom field in your deployment

Comment: I have exactly the same error on the same field, interested in the solution...

Comment: Same error for a custom field of a custom object, but intermittent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing the below resolved my issue:

The xxx.objectTransalation-meta.xml file was not present due to which it was throwing an error. Create a file give the exact name(Transalation Object Name) to it. This should resolve the error

Please refer to below snapshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/At8VZ.png